# Vectorial Analysis , convert from Cartesian (x,y,z) to Cylindrical (ρ,θ,z)

Tags: vector-analysis

r= $5t^2 $ 
$\sqrt{1-t^2}$ i +$5t^3$j + $3t^2$ k

I was trying to convert that exercice and find 
speed and acceleration in cilindrycal coordinates but somehow I got lost because what I have

$x=pcos\theta$;
$y=psen\theta$;
z=z

and $e\theta$ =-$sen\theta$i+$cos\theta$j,
$ep$ =$cos\theta$i+$sen\theta$j
ez=ez

When I try to convert I always got messy results with $cos\theta$ and $sen\theta$

REsult:
r= $10tep$i + $5t^2 $ /
$\sqrt{1-t^2}$$e$$\phi$j + 6$tk$

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: @Natasha  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done it ;)    thank you for your help. I reaaaaaaaaally appreciate it . And also to math.stackexchange.com community :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- $x=5t^2\sqrt{1-t^2}$
- $y=5t^3$
- $z=3t^2$

then

- $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{25t^4(1-t^2)+25t^6}=5t^2$

since $x$ is always positive

- $\theta = \arctan \frac{y}{x}=\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

Comment: thank you gimusi!

Comment: @Natasha You are welcome! Bye